# Poetry 1.1.11 | Unable to find installation candidates for

Tags: python, azure, python-poetry

I wanted to add a dependency for `pathlib` package.

**Specification:**

- Windows 10,
- Visual Studio Code,
- Ubuntu Bash.

**Errors:**

- `401 Client Error` (solved),
- `Unable to find installation candidates for` all packages.

Terminal (updated):

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ poetry add pathlib
Using version ^1.0.1 for pathlib

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (119.0s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 55 installs, 14 updates, 0 removals

  • Updating grpcio (1.41.0 -> 1.41.1): Pending...
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  • Updating grpcio (1.41.0 -> 1.41.1): Failed
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  RuntimeError
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  Unable to find installation candidates for grpcio (1.41.1)
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       68│
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       69│             links.append(link)
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       70│
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       74│             )
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       75│
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       76│         # Get the best link
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Pending...
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  • Updating protobuf (3.18.1 -> 3.19.1): Failed
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│ 
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  RuntimeError
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  Unable to find installation candidates for protobuf (3.19.1)
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       68│
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       69│             links.append(link)
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       70│
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       74│             )
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       75│
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       76│         # Get the best link
  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│

  • Updating pyparsing (2.4.7 -> 3.0.4): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyparsing (3.0.4)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for 
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link

  • Updating sqlalchemy (1.4.25 -> 1.4.26): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for sqlalchemy (1.4.26)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link

  • Updating traitlets (5.1.0 -> 5.1.1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for traitlets (5.1.1)

  at ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link


Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

[GitHub Issue post](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4701)

---

## Solutions

**`401 Client Error`**
I needed to provide an Azure DevOps PAT.
[Microsoft Docs | Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

**`Unable to find installation candidates for ...`**
(Pending solution)