# Unable to find installation candidates for nvidia-cudnn-cu11 when trying to install kornia

Tags: python, nvidia, python-poetry, kornia

I'm trying to install `kornia` using `poetry`.

**System details**

- Python 3.8.5 (I *have* to use this version)
- poetry 1.1.13 (upgrading to v1.2 is not an option)

I've previously installed `kornia` (`poetry add kornia`) but for some unknown reason I'm now getting the following traceback:

> RuntimeError
>
> Unable to find installation candidates for nvidia-cudnn-cu11
> (8.5.0.96)
>
> at ~.poetry\lib\poetry\installation\chooser.py:72 in choose_for
> 68│
> 69│             links.append(link)
> 70│
> 71│         if not links:
> →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
> 73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
> 74│             )

Since this wasn't a very helpful traceback I thought I'd try to pip install to see if I could get `kornia` installed somehow, then repeat the process using `poetry`.

First I ran `poetry run pip install nvidia-pyindex`, then `poetry run pip install kornia`.  `kornia` was installed, giving me confidence that I might be able to do the same using `poetry`.

So I ran `poetry add nvidia-pyindex` which installed, but when I ran `poetry add kornia` I got the same `RuntimeError`.

I wondered if having `poetry add` without `pip uninstall` might have caused issues. So I started from scratch - I ran:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/pypoetry/cache/repositories/pypi/
poetry rm {name of venv}
git checkout master pyproject.toml poetry.lock
poetry add nvidia-pyindex
```

which created the venv (by the same name as previously - not sure if this is an issue in itself, since the name of the venv was first created in PyCharm and I wonder if there are some files lingering in places I don't know that is the root of my problems?), then `poetry add kornia` but got the same error.

I also tried to clear poetry's cache as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802816/unable-to-find-installation-candidates-in-poetry-trying-to-install-genicam) but that didn't help.  I didn't find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811123/poetry-1-1-11-unable-to-find-installation-candidates-for).  I don't believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822702/poetry-was-not-installed-with-the-recommended-installer-cannot-update-automatic) applies since poetry was installed properly and is working fine otherwise.  I read through [this](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4688) but didn't see any working solution.  I tried a fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3456), which was to add

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "nvidia"
url = "https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com"
secondary = true
```

to `pyproject.toml`, hoping that it would avoid the error when poetry tries to install `nvidia-cudnn-cu11`, but it didn't help either.

I tried `poetry add nvidia-cudnn-cu11` and `poetry add nvidia-cudnn-cu116` hoping that having added the ndvidia repo as a secondary source would get `kornia`'s dependencies installed before trying to install `kornia` itself.

{I don't know if secondary sources are only used when `poetry add`ing a package (i.e. `kornia`) and "ignored" for installation of dependencies (`nvidia-cudnn-cu11`) of the package to be installed (`kornia`).}

In any case, that didn't work either.

Running `poetry source add nvidia https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com` didn't work - presumably because `poetry source add` was added to `poetry` v1.2 and was not part of v1.1.13.

I also tried `poetry add --source nvidia https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com` but I got

> PermissionError
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2t6am7ei'
>
> at ~.poetry\lib\poetry\utils\helpers.py:101 in download_file
> 97│
> 98│     with get(url, stream=True) as response:
> 99│         response.raise_for_status()
> 100│
> → 101│         with open(dest, "wb") as f:
> 102│             for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
> 103│                 if chunk:
> 104│                     f.write(chunk)

I'm out of ideas and hoped someone might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could this be related to this problem?

- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6939
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/88049

I had a similar issue and was able to fix it by making the torch dependency explicit and install torch version < 1.13:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
torch = "~1.12.1"
```